# Capturing Data Sent Via TCP with PHP

Tags: php, sockets

I'm trying to capture data sent from several machines over tcp sockets with a PHP script. It looks like I'm not getting all of the data and I think it could be because of the way the script is written. I need some help with it.

```html
#!/usr/bin/php -q 
<?php 
/** 
  * Listens for requests and forks on each connection 
  */ 

$__server_listening = true; 

error_reporting(E_ALL); 
set_time_limit(0); 
ob_implicit_flush(); 
declare(ticks = 1); 

become_daemon(); 

/* handle signals */ 
pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, 'sig_handler'); 
pcntl_signal(SIGINT, 'sig_handler'); 
pcntl_signal(SIGCHLD, 'sig_handler'); 

/* change this to your own host / port */ 
server_loop("10.0.3.49", 9009); 

/** 
  * Change the identity to a non-priv user 
  */ 
function change_identity( $uid, $gid ) 
{ 
    if( !posix_setgid( $gid ) ) 
    { 
        print "Unable to setgid to " . $gid . "!\n"; 
        exit; 
    } 

    if( !posix_setuid( $uid ) ) 
    { 
        print "Unable to setuid to " . $uid . "!\n"; 
        exit; 
    } 
} 

/** 
  * Creates a server socket and listens for incoming client connections 
  * @param string $address The address to listen on 
  * @param int $port The port to listen on 
  */ 
function server_loop($address, $port) 
{ 
    GLOBAL $__server_listening; 

    if(($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) 
    { 
        echo "failed to create socket: ".socket_strerror($sock)."\n"; 
        exit(); 
    } 

    if(($ret = socket_bind($sock, $address, $port)) < 0) 
    { 
        echo "failed to bind socket: ".socket_strerror($ret)."\n"; 
        exit(); 
    } 

    if( ( $ret = socket_listen( $sock, 0 ) ) < 0 ) 
    { 
        echo "failed to listen to socket: ".socket_strerror($ret)."\n"; 
        exit(); 
    } 

    socket_set_nonblock($sock); 
    
    echo "waiting for clients to connect\n"; 

    while ($__server_listening) 
    { 
        $connection = @socket_accept($sock); 
        if ($connection === false) 
        { 
            usleep(100); 
        }elseif ($connection > 0) 
        { 
            handle_client($sock, $connection); 
        }else 
        { 
            echo "error: ".socket_strerror($connection); 
            die; 
        } 
    } 
} 

/** 
  * Signal handler 
  */ 
function sig_handler($sig) 
{ 
    switch($sig) 
    { 
        case SIGTERM: 
        case SIGINT: 
            exit(); 
        break; 

        case SIGCHLD: 
            pcntl_waitpid(-1, $status); 
        break; 
    } 
} 

/** 
  * Handle a new client connection 
  */ 
function handle_client($ssock, $csock) 
{ 
    GLOBAL $__server_listening; 

    $pid = pcntl_fork(); 

    if ($pid == -1) 
    { 
        /* fork failed */ 
        echo "fork failure!\n"; 
        die; 
    }elseif ($pid == 0) 
    { 
        /* child process */ 
        $__server_listening = false; 
        socket_close($ssock); 
        interact($csock); 
        socket_close($csock); 
    }else 
    { 
        socket_close($csock); 
    } 
} 

function interact($socket) 
{ 
    $buf = socket_read($socket, 2048, PHP_NORMAL_READ);

 echo $buf . "\n";

 $file = '/home/pi/09282017.log';

 // Open the file to get existing content
 $current = file_get_contents($file);
 // Append a new person to the file
 $current .= date('Y-m-d h:i:s') . ' ' . $buf . "\n";
 // Write the contents back to the file
 file_put_contents($file, $current);

} 

/** 
  * Become a daemon by forking and closing the parent 
  */ 
function become_daemon() 
{ 
    $pid = pcntl_fork(); 
    
    if ($pid == -1) 
    { 
        /* fork failed */ 
        echo "fork failure!\n"; 
        exit(); 
    }elseif ($pid) 
    { 
        /* close the parent */ 
        exit(); 
    }else 
    { 
        /* child becomes our daemon */ 
        posix_setsid(); 
        chdir('/'); 
        umask(0); 
        return posix_getpid(); 

    } 
} 

?>
```

I know it's not working correctly because those machines send the data to another source and they also log it locally. The data sent to this script seems like it gets 1 out of every 2-3 sent to it.

My plan is to put a raspberry pi on the network and have all of the data sent to it, then with php I'll post it to an api online for use there.

Comment: TCP doesn't guarantee how much data you'll receive at one time.   You need to be reading from it until the other side hangs up or if you have some predetermined amount of data to be read.

Comment: @xaxxon Data will be sent 24/7 a little bit everytime but the same amount everytime. 85 characters.

Comment: You're not understanding.   a call to read can return any amount regardless of how big the individual writes were.   You could send 85 bytes and then call read and get 1 byte.  then call read again and get 4 bytes.  then call read again and get the other 80 bytes.  TCP is a stream of bytes.  It has no notion of what sized chunks you wrote in a single call on the sending side.

Comment: So how can I make this work? What am I missing? The clients are sending data and I'm receiving it but I guess its making the first send then staying connected for the next few sends but my script is only grabbing the first send of data and not doing anything with the rest? Should I, Can I make the script timeout after the first receipt of data to be ready for the next?

Comment: Any suggestions @xaxxon

Comment: you need to pick up a book about network programming, as you seem to be missing very fundamental parts of how it works.  sorry I cannot help you more here.

Comment: Seems harsh, but thanks.

Comment: really all I meant is that it's simply not something I can help with on stack overflow.   any book on network programming (especially TCP section) will help you understand what you're missing.   Not saying you're dumb, just that it's limited how much anyone can help on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using netcat to do this and just skipping the PHP option. Why reinvent the will, right?